# Computing $P(X=k)$ as $E(P(X=k|Y))$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$X$ and $Y$ are 2 random variables. I need to compute $P(X=k)$ and I know the distribution of $X|Y$ which is a function of $Y$. Is it correct to say that $P(X=k) = E(P(X=k|Y))$ ?
If yes, how do you show this is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true. To prove it, use $P(X = k \mid Y) = E(1_{\{X = k\}} \mid Y)$ and take expectations using the tower property of expectation.